# asynchronous task for printing docker logs using Python Docker SDK

Tags: python, docker, python-asyncio

Using the Python Docker SDK, I want to create a task that prints logs of a docker container whenever that container outputs anything to stdout or stderr, but while there are no logs to print, it releases the event loop to go off and do other things.

I tried using [client.logs](https://docker-py.readthedocs.io/en/stable/containers.html#docker.models.containers.Container.logs):

```
client = docker.APIClient(base_url='tcp://localhost:2375')
async def my_logging_task():
    while True:
        for log in client.logs('my_container', stdout=True, stderr=True):
            print(log)
         await asyncio.sleep(1)
```

However, this just prints the same integers over and over again. Also not sure why log is an integer.

I tried adding the stream=True parameter to client.logs

Now, I correctly get logging lines being printed, however, now client.logs is blocking and my_logging_task never lets go of the event loop, even when there's no new logs to print.

What's the correct way to make an async task that just prints a docker container's logs?

EDIT June 7 2019:

I also tried using [client.attach](https://docker-py.readthedocs.io/en/stable/containers.html#docker.models.containers.Container.attach):

```
async def my_logging_task():
    stream = self._client.attach('my_container', stdout=True, stderr=True, stream=True, logs=True)
    while True:
        line = next(stream)
        print(line)
        await asyncio.sleep(1)
```

But while this correctly prints logs from my container, none of my other tasks I created ever get called.

Answer (score 1):

Actually, I don't think there is a way to currently do this.
My question is basically the same as this open issue:
https://github.com/docker/docker-py/issues/2136